# Repeated Column Definitions when developing List Template

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, site-column, template

I am using **Visual Studio** to create a state workflow. As part of my solution I am creating a custom Document Library template. The template includes the required custom content type and some custom columns.

It seems that if I want to change the column properties (as part of the development process), I need to make the change in **many** different files. For example, if I want to add the ShowInEditorForm attribute I need to update the following:

1. The `Elements.xml` file for the Site Column
2. The `Elements.xml` file for the Content Type
3. The `Schema.xml` file for the List Template (in two places) -- once in the `<FieldRefs>` attribute and then again in the `<Fields>` attribute

Am I doing this correctly? Why are the attributes repeated over and over? Why can't I just define the default properties once and then have them used when referenced?

**Edit -- Updated Findings**

As far as I can tell, it looks like that at any point in the "chain" the properties can be overwritten. It also looks like, up to a certain point, the properties do not have to be repeated.

With that said, I was able to reduce the **Elements.xml** file for the Content Type down to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <!-- Parent ContentType: Document (0x0101) -->
    <ContentType ID="0x010100E28D2FB8531146D582E6FC3729433EFF"
        ...
        ...
            <FieldRef ID="{f41f6d8e-ca33-4867-af14-adedba9b0eb1}"
                      Name="KnowledgeBaseArticleStatus" />
            <FieldRef ID="{48235e6d-92d7-4c9e-94ef-24054c81fb83}"
                      Name="KnowledgeBaseTechnicalReviewBy" />
        ...
        ...
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

I still need **both** the `ID` and `Name` but I can leave the rest of the attributes out. And it seems that I still must have the attributes repeated in the `Schema.xml` file.